# Google Cardboard iOS camera not render properly

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I used google cardboard in my iOS app. It works properly in unity editor but when I run app on device, both camera not render properly. Any solution?

Comment: You need to share more information on your issue. Otherwise it is nearly impossible to solve it.

Comment: use `void OnRenderProperly() { }`